# Resource Usage between 12.04 LTS, 12.10 and 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, boot, 13.04

I've finally decided to use ubuntu for my dev machine. however my question is what Ubuntu is really suited for my tasks.

What I am generally looking for

- Who has less resource usage, Ubuntu 12.04 ,ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04
- Who's more stable? Ubuntu 12.04 ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04

I will be primarily using this OS for developing web applications (Java EE, Scala and Ruby)

Who use less resouces(CPU and RAM)?Ubuntu 12.04 ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 (a benchmark  would  also really help and who boots faster)

My System Specifications

- AMD APU A6 Dual Core 2.7GHZ
- 8GB of Ram

**UPDATED THE QUESTION**

I didn't know that there's a newer version of Ubuntu. so I added and updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about resources, both are going to be more or less equals because both use Unity, but Ubuntu 12.10 adds a Amazon lens and some previsualization ones, which maybe use more memory than the 12.04, and the same with Ubuntu 13.04 (adds more graphical changes as the shutdown menu) but Unity is more debugged at this stage. And, obviously, Ubuntu 12.04 is more stable than 12.10 because it's a LTS version (Long Term Supported) and is older than 12.10 (which is not a LTS release). The same occurs with 13.04.

As a personal mark, I use LTS version until the non LTS version gives me enough stability or features. In my case nowadays, this depends of the graphic card support, and Ubuntu 12.04 has full support with my AMD driver and Ubuntu 13.04 not yet.

And I use Ubuntu 12.04.2 to daily use, to install my home server and code with C, C++, Java, Scala, Scheme, Python, PHP...

Comment: I've updated my question and added 13.04. when I say resources I also mean CPU usage

Comment: Yes, when we are talking about resources we talk about RAM memory and CPU, factors that appear in runtime. I'll update my answer with 13.04, but is more or less the same as I said with 12.10.